# getGeoPoint() method returns null when called. There is more than 1 document in the Firebase collection

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-android-api-2

I'm following a tutorial on building a Chatroom app that includes **User Location** functionality with Google Maps API, however, I'm following it just to learn how to use the Google Maps API, I'm trying to build a Tracking App that can record traveled routes and access them by date, etc.

There is a `UserLocation` object comprised of **geolocation, timestamp, and a User object**, and instances of it are stored in a Firestore Collection. The database works fine:

[image]

However, after authentication I'm getting the following error:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.trackingapp, PID: 13386
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'com.google.firebase.firestore.GeoPoint com.example.trackingapp.models.UserLocation.getGeo_point()' on a null object reference
        at com.example.trackingapp.ui.MainActivity.setCameraView(MainActivity.java:109)
        at com.example.trackingapp.ui.MainActivity.onMapReady(MainActivity.java:410)
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.zzac.zza(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.zzaq.dispatchTransaction(Unknown Source)
        at com.google.android.gms.internal.maps.zzb.onTransact(Unknown Source)
        at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:499)
        at ds.b(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@203615052@20.36.15 (040700-0):2)
        at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.bf.run(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_mapsdynamite@203615052@20.36.15 (040700-0):2)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

I'm guessing I made a mistake trying to implement the original App's logic into mine.

I'm almost certain the problem is how `mUserListEventListener` is used. This variable literally holds all of the logic to get the **UserLocations** into the **ArrayList**, but it is only called in the **OnDestroy()** method!!

The tutorial's source code is written that way, there are no other usages for `mUserListEventListener`. I've tried to implement UserLocations logic elsewhere but I can't get it right.

Here is the relevant MainActivity code. It is the only activity in my App (besides Login and Registration):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements OnMapReadyCallback {

    //    Variables Google Maps
    private boolean mLocationPermissionGranted = false;
    private MapView mMapView;
    private FusedLocationProviderClient mFusedLocationClient;
    private UserLocation mUserLocation;
    private ArrayList<UserLocation> mUserLocations = new ArrayList<>();
    private GoogleMap mGoogleMap;
    private LatLngBounds mMapBoundary;
    private UserLocation mUserPosition;

    //    Variables Firebase
    private FirebaseFirestore mDb;
    private ListenerRegistration mUserListEventListener;
    private Set<String> mUserIds = new HashSet<>();


    //    Otras Variables
    private RecyclerView rvUsers;
    private UserRecyclerAdapter adapter;
    private ArrayList<User> mUserList = new ArrayList<>();
    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        initGoogleMap(savedInstanceState);

        mFusedLocationClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this);

        // DATA DE FIREBASE
        //
        mDb = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
        rvUsers = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.user_list_recycler_view);
        getUsers();
        initUserRecyclerView();
        setUserPosition();
    }

    private void setCameraView(){

        double bottomBoundary = mUserPosition.getGeo_point().getLatitude() - .1;
        double leftBoundary = mUserPosition.getGeo_point().getLongitude() - .1;
        double topBoundary = mUserPosition.getGeo_point().getLatitude() + .1;
        double rightBoundary = mUserPosition.getGeo_point().getLongitude() + .1;

        mMapBoundary = new LatLngBounds(
                new LatLng(bottomBoundary,leftBoundary),
                new LatLng(topBoundary,rightBoundary)
        );

        mGoogleMap.moveCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newLatLngBounds(mMapBoundary,0));
    }

    private void setUserPosition(){
        for (UserLocation userLocation : mUserLocations){
            if (userLocation.getUser().getUser_id().equals(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getUid())){
                mUserPosition = userLocation;
            }
        }
    }

    private void getUserDetails(){
        if (mUserLocation == null){
            mUserLocation = new UserLocation();

            DocumentReference userRef = mDb.collection("Users")
                    .document(Objects.requireNonNull(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getUid()));

            userRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()){
                        Log.d(TAG, "onComplete: successfully set the user details.");

                        User user = task.getResult().toObject(User.class);
                        mUserLocation.setUser(user);
                        ((UserClient)getApplicationContext()).setUser(user);
                        getLastKnownLocation();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
        else {
            getLastKnownLocation();
        }
    }

    private void saveUserLocation(){
        if(mUserLocation != null){
            DocumentReference locationRef = mDb.
                    collection("User Locations")
                    .document(Objects.requireNonNull(FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getUid()));

            locationRef.set(mUserLocation).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Void>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Void> task) {
                    if(task.isSuccessful()){
                        Log.d(TAG, "saveUserLocation: \ninserted user location into database." +
                                "\n latitude: " + mUserLocation.getGeo_point().getLatitude() +
                                "\n longitude: " + mUserLocation.getGeo_point().getLongitude());
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }

    private void getLastKnownLocation() {
        Log.d(TAG, "getLastKnownLocation: called");

        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return;
        }
        mFusedLocationClient.getLastLocation().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Location>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Location> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()){
                    Location location = task.getResult();
                    GeoPoint geoPoint = new GeoPoint(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude());
                    Log.d(TAG, "onComplete: latitude: " + geoPoint.getLatitude());
                    Log.d(TAG, "onComplete: longitude" + geoPoint.getLongitude());

                    mUserLocation.setGeo_point(geoPoint);
                    mUserLocation.setTimestamp(null);
                    saveUserLocation();
                }
            }
        });
    }


private void getUsers() {

        CollectionReference usersCollection = mDb
                .collection("Users");

        mUserListEventListener = usersCollection.addSnapshotListener(new EventListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onEvent(@Nullable QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots, @Nullable FirebaseFirestoreException e) {
                Log.d(TAG, "onEvent: called.");

                if (e != null) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "onEvent: Listen failed.", e);
                    return;
                }

                if(queryDocumentSnapshots != null){

                    // Clear the list and add all the users again
                    mUserList.clear();
                    mUserList = new ArrayList<>();

                    for (QueryDocumentSnapshot doc : queryDocumentSnapshots) {
                        User user = doc.toObject(User.class);
                        mUserList.add(user);
                        getUserLocation(user);
                    }

                    Log.d(TAG, "onEvent: user list size: " + mUserList.size());
                }

            }
        });

    }

    private void getUserLocation(User user){
        DocumentReference locationRef = mDb.collection("User Locations")
                .document(user.getUser_id() );

        locationRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()){
                    if(task.getResult().toObject(UserLocation.class) != null){
                        mUserLocations.add(task.getResult().toObject(UserLocation.class));
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }


    @Override
    protected void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        if (checkMapServices()) {
            if (mLocationPermissionGranted) {
                getUsers();
                getUserDetails();
            } else {
                getLocationPermission();
            }
        }
        mMapView.onResume();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        mMapView.onStart();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        super.onStop();
        mMapView.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(GoogleMap map) {
        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(new LatLng(0, 0)).title("Marker"));
        if (ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this,
                Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            return;
        }
        map.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
        mGoogleMap = map;
        setCameraView();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        mMapView.onPause();
        super.onPause();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        mMapView.onDestroy();
        super.onDestroy();
        if(mUserListEventListener != null){
            mUserListEventListener.remove();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onLowMemory() {
        super.onLowMemory();
        mMapView.onLowMemory();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Having a `NullPointerException` is not the same as returning null.
In this case, as the error trace indicates, in here:

`at com.example.trackingapp.ui.MainActivity.setCameraView(MainActivity.java:109)`

There was a call to an null obj.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 
    'com.google.firebase.firestore.GeoPoint 
     com.example.trackingapp.models.UserLocation.getGeo_point()'
     on a null object reference
```

This is here `mUserPosition.getGeo_point()`.

The error indicates that `mUserPosition` is null, you need to initialize it first.

Probably (this I do not know) you need to call `getUserDetails` if the var `mUserPosition` is null.

```
if (mUserPosition == null) {
    getUserDetails();
}
```